# Number is an integer

Tags: number-theory

The numbers $$N_{n}=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)...(n-1+s+t+u+...)}{s!t!u!...}$$ for $n-1=s+2t+3u+...\quad s,t,u,...\in\mathbb{N}$ should be integers.

Do you see why? It looks a bit like a multinomial coefficient, but I could conclude something with that.

We can expand with $n!$, maybe you see some multinomial coefficient. But if yes, we are finish, because multinomial coefficients are integers.

Thanky you for you interest.

Comment: Rewrite it so $s = a_{1}$, $t = a_{2}$, up to some $a_{N}$. Then $n-1 = \sum_{m=1}^{N}m a_{m} \equiv A$. 

To make this look like a multi-nomial consider having $X = A + a_{1} + a_{2} + \ldots + a_{N}$ things. We could write this entirely in terms of the $a_{n}$ but it isn't necessary, all that is important is we have some integer X of things which is definitely bigger than $a_{1}+a_{2}+\ldots+a_{N}$, a trivial statement since A is definitely not negative.

Draw $a_{1}$ objects from a set of size X, then $a_{2}$ etc up to $a_{N}$ what do you get? How does it relate to your expression?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am sorry but I don't get what you mean. Do you want to make an answer?

Comment: The variable $s,t,u,...$ are nonnegative integers, and they sum to at most $n-1$.  The only boundary case is $s=n-1$ and the other variables are zero.  So these are multinomial coefficients.  The OP is doubtless reading from (11) and (12) on [Series Reversion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html) at Wolfram MathWorld.

Comment: I'm headed to the library to get the book (Methods of Mathematical Physics, vol. 1 by Morse and Feshbach, 1953).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can prove this by 'rolling' the numerator from $n!$ to $(n-1+s+t+u+...)!$ ($(k)!$ is a falling factorial), e.g. $n!\to2\dots(n+1)\to3\dots(n+2)\to\dots(n+k)!\to\dots$, and prove they are always integers, which involves periodic properties of prime numbers.